# Archiving records on the expiration date of publication

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of records in which information about the records is stored: name, description, date ...

```
 id |  name  | ... |    date    |
---------------------------------
  1 | name 1 | ... | 2019-02-20 |
  2 | name 2 | ... | 2019-02-27 |
  3 | name 3 | ... | 2019-05-21 |
```

I need this result:

```
 id |  name  | ... |    date    |
---------------------------------
  2 | name 2 | ... | 2019-02-27 |
```

How to make a request?

Comment: A table has _rows_, not records. And _columns_, not fields.

Comment: where date > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Comment: How come you don't want the id=3 row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below-

```
select * from tablename where date>=now()::date
```

Comment: Does your first query give the result in the question?

Comment: @ikram, as I wrote it first, so i didn't change it

Answer (score 1):

try like below by using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
 select t.* from tbale t where date>=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date
```